# Recursive function not working for to get innermost exception message

Tags: java, recursion, exception

I have written this method

```
    private string FindInnerExceptionMessage(Exception ex)
    {
        string exceptionMsg = string.Empty;
        if (ex.InnerException == null)
        {
            exceptionMsg = ex.Message;
        }
        else
        {
            ex = ex.InnerException;
            FindInnerExceptionMessage(ex);
        }
        return exceptionMsg;
    }
```

However, after that FindInnerExceptionMessage it is stepping to return exceptionMsg and not logging the exact exception message

Comment: I guess I could be wrong but isn't this C# code?  The thread is tagged with java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually assign the return value of your recursive call to anything. As a result, your first call will return `String.Empty` because the value of `FindInnerExceptionMessage(ex.InnerException)` is never assigned as the return value (unless the exception passed to the first call has no inner exception, in which case it will work). Try something like this:

```
private string FindInnerExceptionMessage(Exception ex)
{
    string exceptionMsg = string.Empty;
    if (ex.InnerException == null)
    {
        exceptionMsg = ex.Message;
    }
    else
    {
        exceptionMsg = FindInnerExceptionMessage(ex.InnerException);
    }
    return exceptionMsg;
}
```